# Macro to copy data from one workbook to all other workbooks in a specific folder

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy a master project list from one workbook to all of the other workbooks in a specific folder. I have tried - see my macro below. While the macro does not give me any errors, I also cannot get it to work... Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance!!

```
Sub Macro1()
   Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
   file = Dir("C:\Users\New folder")
   While (file <> "")

    Workbooks("Master Project list (2).xlsx").Sheets("Master Project list").Range("A1:D34").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(file).Activate
    Sheets("Master Project list").Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Exit Sub
    file = Dir
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub Macro1()
   Dim file As String
   Dim myPath As String
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim rng As Range

   Dim wbMaster As Workbook
   'if master workbook already opened
   Set wbMaster = Workbooks("Master Project list (2).xlsx")
   'if master workbook is not opened
   'Set wbMaster = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\New folder\Master Project list (2).xlsx")

   Set rng = wbMaster.Sheets("Master Project list").Range("A1:D34")

   myPath = "C:\Users\New folder\" ' note there is a back slash in the end
   file = Dir(myPath & "*.xls*")
   While (file <> "")

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myPath & file)
        rng.Copy
        With wb.Worksheets("Master Project list").Range("A1")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        End With

        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        Set wb = Nothing

        file = Dir
    Wend

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: maybe there is no excel files in this folder `"C:\Users\New folder\"`? have you missed `<username>` : `"C:\Users\<username>\New folder\"`?

Comment: There are four excel files in the folder and I have added the rest of the path in my macro - just took my username out of the path when I posted  the code here....