# VBA Excel Copy Data from specific worksheet to a specific worksheet in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I need to write a MACRO which copies a table from a specific worksheet, to a specific worksheet (Sheet 3) in a  master workbook, in the first empty row.

Ideally I would like to have the MACRO apply to all files in a specific folder.  Pulling from different workbooks have a worksheet named "Sheet 3". ("Sheet 3" is just a placeholder)

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Master()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim erow

Workbooks.Open Filename:= "C:\Example\File.xlsx"
Sheets("Sheet 3").Select
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Workbooks("MASTER").Sheets("Sheet 3").Activate 
'MASTER is the name of the Master Workbook
erow = Sheets("Sheet 3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Selection.Paste 
'This is where the MACRO gives a "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support
'this property or method"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049662/macro-to-copy-data-from-one-workbook-to-all-other-workbooks-in-a-specific-folder/22049843#22049843

Comment: the answer copies a master workbook into many workbooks.  I want to do the opposite, copy data from many workbooks into one.

Comment: and what the problem? just change 4 lines of code. Logic is the same

Comment: Could you please help me figure out which lines of code to change.  I am still new at this...  I've been playing around with it for the last hour, and had no success.

Comment: this lines: `rng.Copy
        With wb.Worksheets("Master Project list").Range("A1")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        End With` Make the logic reverse

Comment: How would I make the logic reverse?

Comment: Ok, explain please in details what the macro should do:)

Comment: I ended up writing my own.  Thank you for your help!